# Calculating walking distance using Google Maps in R

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been tying to get the distance between a list of home postcodes and a list of school postcodes for approximately 2,000 students. I'm using the `gmapsdistance` package within R to get this from the Google Maps Distance Matrix API. I've put in a valid API key and just replaced this in the following code for security reasons.

```
library(gmapsdistance)
set.api.key("valid API key")

results <- gmapsdistance(origin = school$HomePostcode, 
                         destination = school$SchoolPostcode, 
                         mode = "walking", 
                         shape = "long")
```

However, this gives the following error code.

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>     Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to maps.googleapis.com:443

Looking on the Google APIs website, it looks like it hasn't ran the query for all the data, it says that there were only 219 requests. I know I'm limited as to how many requests I can do in one day, but the limit is 2,500 and it's not even letting me get close to that.

I've tried running the code on one set of postcodes, like below;

```
test <- gmapsdistance(origin = "EC4V+5EX",
                      destination = "EC4V+3AL",
                      mode = "walking",
                      shape = "long")
```

Which gives the following, as I would expect.

```
$Time
[1] 384

$Distance
[1] 497

$Status
[1] "OK"
```

My data looks something like this, I've anonymised the data and removed all variables that aren't needed. There are 1,777 sets of postcodes.

```
head(school)
  HomePostcode   SchoolPostcode
1     EC4V+5EX         EC4V+3AL
2     EC2V+7AD         EC4V+3AL
3     EC2A+1WD         EC4V+3AL
4     EC1V+3QG         EC4V+3AL
5     EC2N+2PT         EC4V+3AL
6     EC1M+5QA         EC4V+3AL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment but have you tried to set the parameter `combinations` to `"pairwise"`. If set to `"all"` then it will compute all the combinations between one origin and all destinations.

```
library(gmapsdistance)

from <- c("EC4V+5EX", "EC2V+7AD", "EC2A+1WD", "EC1V+3QG", "EC2N+2PT", "EC1M+5QA")
to <- c("EC4V+3AL", "EC4V+3AL", "EC4V+3AL", "EC4V+3AL", "EC4V+3AL", "EC4V+3AL")

test <- gmapsdistance(origin=from, 
                        destination=to,
                        combinations="pairwise",
                        key="YOURAPIKEYHERE",
                        mode="walking")

test$Distance

        or       de Distance
1 EC4V+5EX EC4V+3AL      497
2 EC2V+7AD EC4V+3AL      995
3 EC2A+1WD EC4V+3AL     2079
4 EC1V+3QG EC4V+3AL     2492
5 EC2N+2PT EC4V+3AL     1431
6 EC1M+5QA EC4V+3AL     1892
```

With this small set of 6 destinations it works, I have an API key, if you send me a bigger set I can try.

Another option would be to use the package `googleway`, it allows to set as well an API key. Example:

```
library(googleway)

test <- google_distance(origins = from,
                      destinations = to,
                      mode = "walking",
                      key="YOURAPIKEYHERE")
```